# In Swift, how to use generic type for an argument of a function?

Tags: swift, generics

I defined a generic class in Swift.

```
    class MyClass<T> {
        
    }
```

I can instantiate `MyClass<Int>` and assign it to a variable whose type is `MyClass` without errors:

```
    func f1() {
        
        // ok
        let a = MyClass<Int>()
        
        // ok
        var b: MyClass = a
    }
```

But I can not use `MyClass` for a function argument:

```
    // build error: Reference to generic type 'MyClass' requires arguments in <...>. Insert '<Any>'.
    func f2(c: MyClass) {
    }
```

I modified the code as Xcode suggests. And the error disappeared:

```
    // ok
    func f3(c: MyClass<Any>) {
    }
```

But I can't pass a object of `MyClass<Int>` to this function:

```
    func f4() {
        // ok
        let a = MyClass<Int>()
        
        // build error: Cannot convert value of type 'MyClass<Int>' to expected argument type 'MyClass<Any>'
        f3(c: a)
    }
```

Why can't I use `MyClass` for a function argument?

And why doesn't `MyClass<Any>` accept `MyClass<Int>`?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of the linked question. Please post here if you believe there's more to your question that isn't covered there, and we can reopen.

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you for the comment. In the linked question, `self as! Thing<Foo>` is not upcasting. And Xcode no longer generates a error for the code in the linked question in Swift 5. But `basket(Basket<Apple>) as Basket<Fruit>` is upcasting. In my question, I wrote 2 questions. Converting `MyClass<Int>` to `MyClass<Any>` may be upcasting. If it is upcasting, why can't I use `MyClass` instead of `MyClass<Any>` for the function argument? `MyClass` can be used for a variable and it can store `MyClass<Int>`.

Comment: @RobNapier And in Swift, casting `Int` to `Any` is not upcasting. `var v1: Int = 1; var v2: Any = v1` is legal, because in Swift, `Any` is not a superclass of `Int`. `Any` means "any type can be accepted". So, I think Swift should accept `MyClass<Int>` for the function argument of type `MyClass<Any>` or `MyClass`.

Comment: @RobNapier Because `Any` means "any type can be accepted" and `Any` is not a superclass of `Int`, setting `Int` variable to `Any` variable is not upcasting. In the same way, setting or passing `MyClass<Int>` to `MyClass<Any>` is not upcasting. My question is nothing to do with upcasting.

Comment: In your `f1()` example `b` is implicitly a `MyClass<Int>`. Note you cannot put this in that function: `var c: MyClass<Any> = b`. It will error out by telling you that you "Cannot assign value of type 'MyClass<Int>' to type 'MyClass<Any>'". It has nothing to do with upcasting, you are dealing with two different and distinct types.

Comment: I can already hear you say, "But I can cast an `Int` to an `Any`." Yes you can, but you aren't trying to do that here, you are trying to cast a `MyClassInt` to a `MyClassAny` (I removed the `<>` to make why it doesn't work more obvious...) You *could* cast a `MyClass<Int>` to an `Any`...

Comment: @DanielT. Thank you for the comments. You're right. When I add `b = MyClass<String>()`, Xcode says "Cannot assign value of type 'MyClass<String>' to type 'MyClass<Int>'". `b` is implicitly a `MyClass<Int>`. I thought logically `MyClass<Int>` should be able to be converted to `MyClass<Any>`. And there should be a superclass like `MyClass`. But `MyClass<Int>`, `MyClass<String>`, and `MyClass<Any>` have properties and methods whose data types are `Int`, `String`, and `Any` respectively. So, they are different and incompatible classes and there is no superclass like `MyClass` for them.

Comment: @DanielT. My understanding about the superclass in my last comment was wrong. `MyClass<Int>`, `MyClass<String>`, and `MyClass<Any>` are different but they also have common part. Properties and methods which does not use generic types in `MyClass<T>` are the common part between `MyClass<Int>`, `MyClass<String>`, and `MyClass<Any>`. So, I thought there should be a superclass `MyClass`. But Swift does not implicitly create the superclass `MyClass` for them. I have to explicitly create `SuperMyClass` which does not use generic types and make `MyClass<T>` inherit `SuperMyClass`.

Comment: `Any` does not mean "any type can be accepted." `Any` is a protocol that every type conforms to. That may feel similar, but it isn't because of existentials. `let x: Any = 5` and `let x:Int = 5` don't even allocate the same memory. `Thing<Any>` is not a supertype of `Thing<Int>` in Swift. They are two independent, and unrelated types. The linked question discusses why this is the case, and what bad things happen if you allow it. Those bad things could be resolved with an additional language feature called covariance that Swift does not have today, except in the special case of Array.

Comment: Try creating a variable of type Int and one of type Any and then check `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:)`. You'll find them different (8 bytes vs 32 bytes). Using the word "cast" unfortunately confuses people a lot, because in a language like C, "cast" means "treat these bytes as this other type." In Swift, `as` can sometimes do that, but it can also cause the creation of an existential container, possibly allocating heap memory, and copy the data over. `Any` in Swift often refers to that existential container itself, not just "anything you want."

Comment: @RobNapier https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyobject says AnyObject is the protocol to which all classes implicitly conform. But I can't find the documentation of Any. How can I know Any is a protocol? Where is the documentation for Any?

Comment: @RobNapier And Daniel T.'s comment is the right answer to the question. Could you open the question again? Or, change the reason for closing the question.

Comment: `Any` is explained in [Type Casting for Any and AnyObject](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/typecasting#Type-Casting-for-Any-and-AnyObject). Full documentation is in the Language Reference: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/types#Any-Type